# Duplicate line short cut does not work in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have Visual Studio 2013 and Resharper installed.
Until recently when I pressed Ctrl D, Ctrl D I was able to duplicate the line I was on.
Now it does not work.
How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Keyboard`. Then select command `ReSharper.ReSharper_DuplicateText` from list (autocomplete works).You may press Ctrl+D and assign it to selected command. It's possible to set scope (`Global` etc.). By default I have `Text Editor` and `XAML` scopes.